# Weird face after Boolean..?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I used the Boolean modifier to make a hole in my gun and it looks like a shadery face covering up the hole. It's a bit hard to see and it isn't really a face. The hole i made goes through 3 meshes.

(You need to click on the pic to see the shady face)
[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Faces of one object are overlapping with faces of another object. They're in the same position. Push them away a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the 3 meshes' faces are overlapping. Move the faces of 2 of your 3 objects a tiny bit away (along normals or X/Y/Z).

Comment: It's known as [Z-fIghting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)